# Azure Bot Framework Echo Bot NullReferenceException

Tags: nullreferenceexception, .net-core-3.1, azure-bot-service, botframework

I just created a new bot with bot framework V4 using the Bot Framework v4 SDK Templates for VS 2019. I created a new Echo bot based on .net core 3.1, when I run it and try to use it with the Emulator, I get an exception right away as this:

[image: Exception Image]

> System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'

Any idea?

Detailed Stacktrace: https://gist.github.com/M365Devme/74e0aab0b4cbade9900835bd0cc6b097

This is the project I used:
[image]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please have a look at the handy guide to see the steps you can take to get a better answer faster: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I cannot reproduce your problem. Please edit the (correctly formatted) stack trace into your question. And can you link to the specific template you're using?

Comment: @KyleDelaney I modified the question to include required information. I pasted a screenshot of the project, but what do you mean by a link to the template? I added it from the extensions in VS 2019.

Comment: I meant a link to the Visual Studio marketplace, like this: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=BotBuilder.botbuilderv4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [this comment](https://github.com/microsoft/botframework-sdk/issues/6153#issuecomment-757042216):

> This is a known issue in 4.11 sdk.  The exception is internally caught, and can be safely ignored.  More information can be found here: https://github.com/microsoft/botbuilder-dotnet/issues/4867